# limit fields on elasticsearch response but still serialize using jackson

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, jackson

I have successfully created an index using elasticsearch, and can serialized those exact json payloads back to my java application.

```
for (SearchHit searchHit : searchResponse.getHits()) {
        try {
            result.getItems().add(objectMapper.readValue(searchHit.getSourceRef().streamInput(), Program.class));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot marshall json", e);
        }
    }
```

The payload size that I export to elasticsearch is very large, but the response, I want to be very small. I also want to allow the client to dynamically include or exclude some fields. So I did this, where fields is an array of fields I want to include. This works well in that only the fields I ask for are returned, however the searchHit.getSourceRef is now null. Is there any way to get it to just copy the fields that I included via Jackson? Or must I always return the entire source object? Or do I have to write some sort of mapping code to translate (I would really like to avoid this) ?

```
 SearchResponse searchResponse = transportClient.prepareSearch("programs")
            .addFields(fields.toArray(new String[fields.size()]))
            .setTypes("program")
            .setQuery(query).setFrom(start).setSize(pageSize)
            .execute().actionGet();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
however the searchHit.getSourceRef is now null.
```

It is null because searchHit.getSource() is also null. As far as I know you have to add "_source" to your fields list when you do the search. Something like this:

```
    ArrayList<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();

    fields. add("field1");
    fields.add("field2");
    fields.add("_source");  // add this field

    SearchResponse response = transportClient.prepareSearch("programs")
            .addFields(fields.toArray(new String[fields.size()]))
            .execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: Ok that is something, but what I am looking to do is have that source only have the fields I specified. Ie maintain its structure but only with those fields